# How get info from WebSocket using php?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I want get last transaction from blockchain.info On this site has API Websocket. But i can use API Websocket only for JavaScript. I can get last transaction using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://ws.blockchain.info/inv');
      conn.onopen = function () {
        console.log('open');
        conn.send('{"op":"unconfirmed_sub"}');
      }
      conn.onclose = function () {
        console.log('close');
      }
      conn.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('websocket error: ' + error);
      }
      conn.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    </script>
```

But i need get info above using php and after save in mysql. How can I get it through php?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the websocket is in JavaScript you will have to send to PHP via AJAX.

Comment: Yes i can use AJAX, but when browser disconnects I lose data. Script must be run on the server in the background. I can not keep all the time open page in the browser.

Comment: What are the end points of the websocket? Isn't the browser one of them?

Comment: You want the JS code containing websocket server to run outside a browser, is that it? If it is, I think you might be talking about [Rhino Shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Shell)

Comment: I found only one solution and it WebSocket. Can you will prompt another?

Comment: You can write websocket _clients_ in PHP the same as you can write a websocket server.  I have used https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-websocket-client successfully in the past

Answer (score 0):

I found a library that solves the problem it [phpws](https://github.com/Devristo/phpws)

Thanks to all.